# Calculate current-column including display properties

Tags: buffers, org-agenda, display, string, text-properties

I am trying to calculate the width of text within either a buffer or a string after it has been displayed, i.e. after taking into account the width of any [`display` properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html), such as embedded images, in the text.

The documentation of `current-column` and `string-width` talks about the displayed representation of strings in the current buffer, but neither takes the `display` property into account:

```el
(require 'org)
(let ((s (propertize " " 'display "123")))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert s)
    (current-column))                   ; => 1
  (string-width s)                      ; => 1
  (org-string-width s))                 ; => 3
```

The problem with `org-string-width` is that it does not work with complex display properties such as images.

This is the best alternative to `current-column` I have come up with so far:

```el
(/ (- (car (window-absolute-pixel-position))
      (car (window-absolute-pixel-position (line-beginning-position))))
   (default-font-width))
```

It approximates the "current window column" by calculating the current X-coordinate as a multiple of the default face font.

Is there a better way to achieve this purpose?

---

My motivation for this question is the misalignment/truncation of Org agenda tags in the presence of `org-agenda-category-icon-alist`. For example, with:

```el
(setq org-agenda-category-icon-alist
      '(("travel"
         "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/status/airplane-mode-symbolic.svg"
         nil nil :ascent center)))
```

I get the following truncation in the agenda buffer:

[image: Org agenda misalignment screenshot]

Luckily, this can be hacked around with some advice:

```el
(define-advice org-agenda-align-tags (:around (align &rest args) my-column)
  "Override `current-column' to include display properties."
  (let ((override (lambda ()
                    (/ (- (car (window-absolute-pixel-position))
                          (car (window-absolute-pixel-position
                                (line-beginning-position))))
                       (default-font-width)))))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (advice-add 'current-column :override override)
               (apply align args))
      (advice-remove 'current-column override))))
```

which no longer causes truncation:

[image]

Comment: Good question......

Comment: I think you could get the right effect using an `:align-to` space specifier before `:tag:`

Comment: @rpluim Thanks, you're right. Patching `org-agenda-align-tags` to use `:align-to` instead of a fixed-width string solves the alignment issue. Would you consider this a bug with `org-agenda.el`?

Comment: I'm not an org developer, but probably. `:align-to` has existed since 2004 or so :-)

Comment: @rpluim I initially read that as "`:align-to` is so 2004". :)